# How to create record from tuple list

Tags: ocaml

How can I create **record** (t) from the **tuple list** ((string * string) list) below?

```
From: [("field1", "foo"); ("field2", "bar"); ("field3", "baz")]

To: { field1: "foo"; field2: "bar"; field3: "baz" }
```

I can make it with mutable fields as shown below but is there another way?

```ml
type t = {
    mutable key1: string;
    mutable key2: string;
    mutable key3: string;
}

let set (key, value) item =
    match key with
    | "key1" -> item.key1 <- value; item
    | "key2" -> item.key2 <- value; item
    | "key3" -> item.key3 <- value; item
    | _ -> item

let to_rec list =
    let rec aux acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | h :: t -> aux (set h acc) t
    in
    aux { key1 = ""; key2 = ""; key3 = "" } list
```

Comment: Why do you need converting from a (dynamic) key-value list to a (static) record,  specifically? Depending on your exact needs, perhaps you should rather be using a Hashtbl or a Map, instead of either the record or the list or both.

Comment: Actually there is no specific need. I am getting data from redis and I thought that it would be more convenient to access specific field if I use records.

Comment: Then there is indeed no reason to use a named tuple for representing a hash table. Use hastables or maps for that. It may be that you can go with associative lists as well, depending on your needs. Finally, you may find out that you don't really need to have any proxy representation in the OCaml heap and instead fully store your information in redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use mutable fields, you can use `with` to update fields of a record, e.g.,

```
let of_list = List.fold_left (fun r (k,v) ->
    match k with
    | "field1" -> {r with field1=v}
    | "field2" -> {r with field2=v}
    | "field3" -> {r with field2=v}
    | s -> invalid_arg ("an unexpected field " ^ s))
   {field1=""; field2=""; field3=""}
```

When you have a predefined input syntax, i.e., you're sure that the fields in the list will be in a specific order (or you just sorted them), you can pattern match directly on the structure of the list, e.g.,

```
let of_list = function
  | ["field1", field1;
     "field2", field2;
     "field3", field3] -> {field1; field2; field3}
  | _ -> invalid_arg "expected the predefined structure"
```

Finally, if the performance doesn't matter very much, you can use `List.assoc` and query the fields, e.g.,

```
let of_list elts = {
  field1 = List.assoc "field1" elts;
  field2 = List.assoc "field2" elts;
  field3 = List.assoc "field3" elts;
}
```

Comment: To complement the `List.assoc`-based solution: if performance *does* matter (but are there records in real-life large enough so that it would matter?), you may turn the input list into a Hashtbl or a Map, then use `Hashtbl.find / Map.find` (dually to @Chris’ answer). If you have control over the input format, maybe you should use one of these data structures from the beginning, instead of a list, as it seems this is the abstraction you really want.

Comment: <cite>But are there records in real-life large enough so that it would matter?</cite>

It is not the size of the record that matters but the size of the list. Though it will be still the O(N) complexity, since the number of fields is constant, so switching to `Map` or `Hashtbl` won't really change the big-O, since you need to spend `O(N)` to build the intermediate data structure.

Comment: My assertion with large records is that you would get decent performance for non-maliciously-long input lists, but I agree we don’t know the specifics of OP’s problem. For such lists, if the number of record fields is K, then the complexity is O(K²) with a key-value list and O(K) with a map. For general lists of length N, it’s O(K×N) versus O(N) but the latter builds a map in memory; to find which is faster, you’d have to compare the time constants involved. You may avoid some of that cost by using a map from the beginning.

Comment: The number of fields is always a constant factor as it depends on the type of the record and never depends on the size of the input. So the number of records will never appear in the big-O notation, so for a general list it will still be O(N).  Another note is that Map is O(logN) and Hashtbl is O(1), not O(N).

Comment: So the first solution with `{r with field1=v}` was new to me and it answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: “Another note is that Map is O(logN) and Hashtbl is O(1), not O(N).” That’s for lookup. I was also accounting for building the map / hash table.

Answer (score 1):

A list can contain any number of elements *or none*. A record type contains exactly a certain number of fields. My mildly educated guess is that you're better served with a [`Hashtbl`](https://ocaml.org/api/Hashtbl.html).

We can readily write a function that will take a list and create a hash table from its contents.

```
let convert_to_hash lst =
  let rec aux h = function
  | [] -> h
  | (k, v)::xs -> Hashtbl.add h k v; aux h xs
  in
  aux (Hashtbl.create 20) lst
```

Alternatively, using sequences:

```
let convert_to_hash lst =
  lst |> List.to_seq |> Hashtbl.of_seq
```

If we call this on your sample data:

```
let h = convert_to_hash [("field1", "foo"); ("field2", "bar"); ("field3", "baz")]
```

And then iterate over that hash table, we can see the result:

```
utop # Hashtbl.iter (Printf.printf "%s => %s\n") h;;
field1 => foo
field3 => baz
field2 => bar
- : unit = ()
```

You might also want to implement this kind of functionality with a [Map](https://ocaml.org/api/Map.S.html), but given that all of your record fields were marked as mutable, the Hashtbl may be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Hashtbl might be a solution too. I have already some codebase with records so I will try that one first. Thanks.